# handler.postDelayed doesn't work

Tags: java, android, handler

I am trying to run 2 `handler.postDelayed` one after another but it doesn't work.

The `MyDraw` function draw on canvas
I change the `x` variable and that should move the picture.
My problem is that it should move to the right then stop and then move to the left
but it doesn't stop.

this is my code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
MyDraw();
handler.postDelayed((new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(x<=40)
    {
        x=x+5;
        MyDraw();
    }
}), 3000);

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(x>=-200)
        {
            x=x-5;
            MyDraw();
        }
    }
}, 3000);
```

this is MyDraw:

```
public void MyDraw()
{
    try {
        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        synchronized(holder) {
            onDraw(canvas);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (canvas != null) {
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

this is onDraw:

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

```
    canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 44, 171, 226));
    bitbattle=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.battlesbackgroundice);
    //canvas.drawBitmap(bit, 0, 0, null);
    Rect src=new Rect(0, 0, bitbattle.getWidth(), bitbattle.getHeight());
    Rect dst=new Rect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()-290);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitbattle,src, dst, null);
    bitash = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.trainer);
    Rect ashsrc=new Rect(0,0,bitash.getWidth(),bitash.getHeight()); 
    Rect ashdst=new Rect(x,y,(x+bitash.getWidth())*2,(y+bitash.getHeight())*2);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitash, ashsrc, ashdst, null);
    bitkeypad = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.keypad);
    Rect keysrc=new Rect(0,0,bitkeypad.getWidth(),bitkeypad.getHeight());
    Rect keydst=new Rect(20,this.getHeight()-270,190,this.getHeight()-100);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitkeypad, keysrc, keydst, null);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The time for the thread to process the messages are the same for both messages (3000). The post delayed function sends a message to a thread but has the thread wait to execute the function. Therefore, essentially, you are telling the main thread to execute both functions In three seconds (one right after another). If you want to simulate a pause in between the two pieces of code, then the length of the pause would be equal to the difference between the two time values passed to each of the postDelayed function.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by creating a difference between the two? i need to change the time that it will stop?

Comment: I was referring to a difference in the wait time value. Currently they are both set to 3000ms.

Comment: I tried to create a diffrence to put 2000 in the last one but it just stopped and didn't do the other function(it didn't move to the left)

Comment: The last one should be a greater value than the first. The second value of the postDelayed method to wait a certain time. Therefore, if tou want the second function to execute after the first function, the second function should havea greater wait time value.

Comment: I tried that to but when the last one was bigger it didn't stopped at all

Comment: Hmmm... thats strange. Is it possible that you could post more of the source code?

Comment: Hmmm...nothing is jumping out at me although I am not familiar with using canvas. Are you still having issues with this?